# Skip "java.net.ConnectException: Connection" error returned on getResponseCode by HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, connection, httpresponse, httpwebresponse

I have a problem. I have a `CSV` file with `URLs` (~12000) witch **response code** I need to check. My program has checked `URLs` one by one. But after 34 iteration my code does fall every time. URL at 34 line doesn't exist. How I can modify my code to next time meeting this error program skip one and continue working.
I've written a code:
    package lt.local;

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class OffersUrlChecker {
    private static final String SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH = "d:\\LENAL\\ZUD\\load\\offers.csv";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (
            Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)
        ){
         Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();
            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
                String url = csvRecord.get(0);
                URL myUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection myUrlCon = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
                int code = myUrlCon.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println(csvRecord.getRecordNumber()+" - "+code+" " + url);
                }
            }/*catch (ConnectException e){
            System.out.println("java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect");
        }*/
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at lt.zudykkaina.OffersUrlChecker.main(OffersUrlChecker.java:29)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It is likely that the other side is blocking requests in quick succession. Try adding some sleep time between requests.

Comment: I've thought like that too, but at 34 line bad URL, I want to upgrade my code to skip that error next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three suggestions to overcome this problem:

1. Embed the calls in a try catch block.
2. Close the URL connection to release resources. You might be accumulating open sockets.
3. After each error wait a bit, before proceeding. Some servers might block you due to hitting their URLs in a very quick sequence.

Something along these lines:

```
public class OffersUrlChecker {

    private static final String SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH = "d:\\LENAL\\ZUD\\load\\offers.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (
                Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)
        ) {
            Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();
            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
                String url = csvRecord.get(0);
                URL myUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection myUrlCon = null;
                try {
                    myUrlCon = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
                    int code = myUrlCon.getResponseCode();
                    System.out.println(csvRecord.getRecordNumber() + " - " + code + " " + url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OffersUrlChecker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                            String.format("Could not read from %s", url), e);
                    // sleep a bit
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        Logger.getLogger(OffersUrlChecker.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING,
                                "Sleep interrupted", e);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (myUrlCon != null) {
                        myUrlCon.disconnect(); // Make sure you close the sockets
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks **gil.fernandes** . Exception was changed: 
`SEVERE: Could not read from https://liebherr.neriba.lt/saldytuvai/liebherr-cb-4815-saldytuvas.html
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Comment: The server refused the connection. They might have some measures in place to prevent automated web crawling. Still you should be able to move on and continuing querying sites with the code above. Even after the exception the process should not die.

Comment: **gil.fernandes** thanks you a lot! It's solution really help me! Some of used methods unknown for me, buy I'll read about them.